# Find records that are most similar to a particular record using mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have mongoose schema like this

```
const keySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  keywords: [String]
})
```

I want to find other posts from the DB that have the most common keywords to one post's keywords. Meaning if one post has:
`keywords = ["arrayitem1", "arrayitem2"]`
Then I wanna find all the records that have the same keywords, even if this record has a lot of other keywords is fine.

Also if there are a lot of records I understand how to limit the number of records returned, but how should I randomize the returned data so the same top 10 records aren't returned again and again?
What I've tried:

`const commonPosts = keySchema.find({keywords: {$in: [['arrayitem1', 'arrayitem2']]}})`

But the above code is returning a big and complex object and so I am unable to understand where to go from there.
Please ask for any more necessary info. Thank you

Comment: Hi, you might be getting back the promise, if that is the case add "await"
   const commonPosts = await  keySchema.find({keywords: {$in: [['arrayitem1', 'arrayitem2']]}})

Comment: @CarloCapuano Thank you that was a silly mistake of me, i added await but it is still returning an empty array as the result.